# How to specify a remote preprocessor include path like 192.0.2.17://usr/include

Tags: c++, c, include, remote-access, preprocessor

Is it possible to specify a C/C++ include path to a remote preprocessor server?

The point here is to have once central location for header files. This makes upgrades, version consistency, and a host of other things much better than people running all willy-nilly including different versions of things.

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**

Typical include. On Linux, would default to `/usr/include/` or the like; in Windows VS, to a location specified in the `$(IncludePath)` variable.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now imagine that we set our include path as follows:

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=192.0.2.17://usr/include;/usr/include;
```

The above would first check the remote server at 192.0.2.17 to see if the `iostream` library existed. Failing this, `/usr/include` would be checked.

This is a bit of a stretch to illustrate the point:

```
#include <192.0.2.17://iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;

}
```

Thanks, Keith :^)

Comment: I think you have to mount a remote drive somehow instead.  sshfs could work on most linux machins and some sort of NFS or SAMBA share could work for windows.  Then you would set your INCLUDE_PATH directive to point to the shared drive.

Comment: Downvote kindly review criteria and explain. This is a well-thought-out question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Why not just use [git](https://git-scm.com)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl git would require each user to clone a repo and have a separate local copy, correct?

Comment: @kmiklas Yes. But you *want* version control *anyway*, so why is that a problem?

Comment: @JesperJuhl hmmmm....... can you add that as a real answer?

Comment: @kmiklas Done..

Comment: For what it's worth, what you're proposing seems to me to fall outside the scope of the C++ language.  It's really an expansion of how the *host* system interprets file systems and file names.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want version control *anyway* you could just use [git](https://git-scm.com) (like thousands of other projects). So each user has a local clone of anything needed.

To answer the original question: No. I'm not aware of any preprocessor supporting such an include scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any compiler that retrieves include files or libraries remotely, so this is not something you can do directly.

The best you can do is have these dependencies on an NFS share that you can mount and then add that path to your include path.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put references to this in the code like that, and as dbush said, you'd have to enhance the preprocessor.

But there might be cute ways to do this within the Make system. That is, if you're using Make (for instance), you could add steps to the Makefile that force a refresh of data.

However, I would suggest this is WRONG because it's not just the include files that need to be fresh. If an include has changed, the related code has probably also changed, and you would need those changes, too. Your magic #include stuff isn't going to do a thing to make sure people have the right code / libraries that the includes are for.

I'm not sure why proper use of source code repositories don't already handle this for you.